# More weightage to a categorical feature for an Autoencoder model

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, unsupervised-learning, autoencoder

I am using autoencoder for anomaly detection. I don't have any labels already and so its unsupervised. If I have categorical variables, I usually one hot encode before giving it to the model. I would like to know if we there is a possibility to give **more weights to one particular categorical feature** before giving it to the model.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: @Did you find a solution to this issue. I need to do the same thing.

Comment: @DeepakSaini Not yet!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean giving more weights to a selected part of the input? If so, then, I believe this is possible with **neural networks**. Each neuron is assigned a random weights at the beginning of training. You can just **initialize the first layer of the neural network model** with some values representing the desired weights and then freeze those neurons.

An automated way of doing this is by using attention mechanism which automatically provides more weights (attention) to a portion of the input data.